# discord.js shading find a user in a specific guild by id

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

My bot use shards. And I try to get user roles in a specific guild by they ids.

**Before sharding**:

```js
const serverSupportGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('myGuildId');
const user = serverSupportGuild.members.cache.get(id);

console.log(user._roles);
```

**Now I try to do this**:

```js
const getServer = async (guildID) => {
    const req = await client.shard.broadcastEval((c, id) => c.guilds.cache.get(id), { 
        context: guildID
    });
    return req.find(res => !!res) || null;
}
```

```js
const serverSupportGuild = await getServer('myGuildId');
console.log("members: ", serverSupportGuild.members);
const user = serverSupportGuild.members.cache.get(id);  ←← log ERROR
console.log("user: ", user);
```

```bash
members: [
  '829707635787825152',
  '660435627757666311'
]
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
```

Before sharding with my method i was able to see all members from my guild with they respective informations.

But now, I just have an array with bot id and my id. **How can I get all members from a guild with shards** ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharding doesn't return complex objects, it returns simple things, like strings, or arrays of strings, as you see in your results.  If you have more complex things to do, you need to do them inside of the broadcastEval context, as that is where the guild/channel/cache/member etc objects are visible.

Perform your tasks, then return from the getServer (which you might want to rename now, given this insight) and continue on with the code after having done the task(s) you wanted on the member(s) etc.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But I still have a question. The broadcastEval permit to access the good shard of the bot which is present on the searched server? Like this:
`c.guilds.cache.get('823275589875793953').members.cache.get(id)`

Comment: broadcast is going to call ALL your clients...one client for every shard.  the server/member you're looking for is on only 1 shard, in 1 client.  so the broadcast will send the message to all.  inside broadcastEval, check to see if "this" client 'has' that guild...and if not, just return...then you know which shard you're talking to.

Comment: Ok thx. I try this:
`const req = await client.shard.broadcastEval((c, id) => {
  const guild = c.guilds.cache.get('823275589875793953');                                        
  if (guild)                                                         
           return guild.members.cache.get(id);                                                                  
 }, { 
        context: userId
    });
 console.log("HERE ", req);
`

But I got this result: 
`
HERE  [ null, null, null ]
`

Comment: this tells you that none of the shards found this ID.  try the console.log inside the "if(guild) block....this is when you have found the guild....if you haven't found it, then you need to check that first, why this is the case.  You can also try "fetch" instead of accessing the cache, in case the guild is uncached.

Comment: Thanks for the help !
`if (guild) {                                                     
    return await guild.members.fetch(id).then(m => m).catch(() => null);                         
}`